# Hiding element based on string content of an element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide one element when the contents of an element contains a specific string with javascript.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML;
var x = y.includes("LTL Freight");
if (x == true) {
  document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").setAttribute("display",
    "none");
}
```

```html
<p id="radio_ship0">LTL Freight</p>
<div id="divCheckoutQuestions">test</div>
```

Comment: You are setting the wrong attribute.
Try this.
`document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").setAttribute("style", "display:none");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML;
    var x = y.includes("LTL Freight");  
    if (x === true) {   
    document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").style.display = "none"
    }
```

try the above one.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize you needed to console log variable first before adding them to conditional logic.

Comment: @HollyWilliford no, you don't need to console log first, it was just for debugging :)

Comment: @HollyWilliford that added by mistake. removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should take .textContent instead of .innerHTML. Also you can avoid declaring the "x" and change the .setAttribute to .style. This way works fine.

```js
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").textContent;

if ( y.includes("LTL Freight")) {
  document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions")
           .style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<p id="radio_ship0">LTL Freight</p>
<div id="divCheckoutQuestions">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if is ok, but you are not hidding the element. Try this:

```
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML;
var x = y.includes("LTL Freight");
if (x == true) {
  // check the .style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").style.display = "none"
}
```

Oh, btw your code could be simplified to this:

```
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML;
if (y.includes("LTL Freight")) {
  document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").style.display = "none"
}
```

You can [Try it here in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w204b9v/)

Answer (score 1):

`display` is not an attribute but a style property , so you cannot set display attribute like that.

```js
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML.trim();
var x = y.includes("LTL Freight");
if (x) {
  document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<p id="radio_ship0">LTL Freight</p>
<div id="divCheckoutQuestions">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
x.style.display = y.includes("LTL Freight") ? "none" : "block" ;
```

```js
var y = document.getElementById("radio_ship0").innerHTML ;
var x = document.getElementById("divCheckoutQuestions") ;
x.style.display = y.includes("LTL Freight") ? "none" : "block" ;
```

```html
<p id="radio_ship0">LTL Freight</p>
<div id="divCheckoutQuestions">test</div>
```